# Html page size to iphone screen

Tags: html, iphone

Actually I added some codes to my html page

```
<meta name= "viewport" content= "width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

I think this should result in a web page that suits all devices

But the result is 
[image: Picture 1]

While the original one is
[image: Picture 2]

And If you will tell me that I can change the picture size, actually I need this size exactly .. 
Because it is the size needed as shown in Picture 2

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you could remove:

```
<meta name= "viewport" content= "width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Because it wouldn't let the user see the whole page.

Comment: What I should add ?

Comment: @AxA I'm not sure about your other code, but you should use relative width values, such as width: 100%.

Comment: Actually when I remove it .. it became better .. but still it didnt showed everything !

Comment: @AxA Honestly, the easiest approach for responsiveness is Bootstrap and Foundation, they're both really great and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {background-size: cover;}
```

background-size: cover; - for element with your background-image)

Answer (score 0):

i'll advice you use css MediaQueries to do the responsiveness. Do something like

```
@media(min-width: your width in px;){
  // Your styles go here.
  // here you can resize the widths and change other styles of your html 
  //elements 
  //  when the device screen equals your defined min-width or above
```

}

then

```
@media(max-width: your width in px;){
  // Your styles go here.
  // here you can resize the widths and change other styles of your html 
  //elements 
  //  when the device screen equals your defined max-width or below
```

}

Hope this helps. For more on responsive style, visit this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp